# Tensor operations

Tags: matrix-equations, tensors, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to do some scientific programming, but I have limited math experience.  My supervisor has given me the following equation I need to solve for $d$:
$$
Y = Xe^{-b\cdot d}.
$$ 
where

- $X$ and $Y$ are $96 \times 96$ matrices,
- and $b$ and $d$ are $3\times 3$ matrices (the '$\cdot$' sing above signifies dot product).

I'm not even sure how I would go about trying to solve for $d$.  It doesn't seem to make sense to rearrange the equation above to
$$
d = \mathrm{inv}(b) \ln(X/Y),
$$
since (1) I'm not sure how dot product works with tensors (do I need to learn dyadic algebra to do this???), but I didn't think you could just do $\mathrm{inv}(b)(b\cdot d)$.  And how are you supposed to end up with a $3\times 3$ matrix if you're multiplying a $3\times 3$ matrix by a $96\times 96$ one?

If anyone could please give suggest some resources or give me some direction, I would be sincerely appreciative, and thank you for your time.

Comment: Perhaps the notation $(b\cdot d)$ is meant to denote the *scalar product* of the two matrices, i.e. $$b\cdot d = \sum_{ij} b_{ij}d_{ij}$$

Comment: That is exactly what it was :)  Thank you so much.